# (Laravel) What is Query Builder equivalent of this Postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel

I have this query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING(col1, col2, col3) WHERE col1='value'
```

Please help me convert this into Query Builder style in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$data = DB::table('table1')
        ->join('table2', 'table1.col1', '=', 'table2.col1')
        ->join('table2', 'table1.col2', '=', 'table2.col2')
        ->join('table2', 'table1.col3', '=', 'table2.col3')
        ->where('col1', '=', 'value')
        ->get();
```